# Dapper ExecuteAsync get a SQLException: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I used Dapper `ExecuteAsync` method to execute a SQL query with params.

```
insertedId =await connection.ExecuteAsync(query,params, transaction);
```

But this error occurs:

> "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition."

The Good table definition:

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Title] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
[GoodEnumId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
[IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
```

And the PaperDetail table definition:

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[GoodId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Length] [float] NULL,
[Width] [float] NULL,
[Grammage] [float] NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
[IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
```

This is the query:

```
declare @Good1Scalar int
create table #Good1 (Id int)

insert into [Good] (Code, Title, GoodEnumId, Date, IsActive, IsDeleted)
output inserted.Id into #Good1
values (@Param2, @Param3, @Param4, @Param5, @Param6, @Param7)

SELECT @Good1Scalar = id from #Good1 
drop table #Good1

insert into [PaperDetail](GoodId, Length, Width, Grammage, Date, IsActive, IsDeleted)                            
values (@Good1Scalar, @Param8, @Param9, @Param10, @Param11, @Param12, @Param13)
```

And this is my params value and DbType object (of DynamicParameters type):

[image: ScreenShot1]
[image: ScreenShot2]

What's wrong?

**Update:**

1. Using SQL Server Profiler I get the final code and run it on the
   SQL server management studio directly. The query has no error. So surely this error message is misleading and the problem is somewhere else.
2. For testing, I remove the transaction and the error disappeared. So
   I noticed that the problem is from the transaction. That's why I
   reviewed the previous method that takes this transaction (calling the QueryMultiple in one method).
3. I replaced the dapper QueryMultiple with a DataAdapter Fill method. and finally, the error disappeared.

Comment: What is the type of `parameters` variable? Please update your question with the code where you declare and fill it.

Comment: As soon as possible.

Comment: @CodeFuller  I added the type information of the variables.

Comment: Maybe param 8-10 are int and no float? Is this the whole query? Really no more parameters declared above somewhere?

Comment: @Simons0n You can see every param DbTypes in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

It's still unclear from the question what is the type of `param` variable passed to Dapper's `ExecuteAsync` call. The preferred way of passing parameters is through `DynamicParameters` bag.

Here is the code that works with your table definitions and the query.

```
DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("Param2", "TheCode");
parameters.Add("Param3", "TheTitle");
parameters.Add("Param4", 4);
parameters.Add("Param5", "2018-01-28");
parameters.Add("Param6", true);
parameters.Add("Param7", false);
parameters.Add("Param8", 300);
parameters.Add("Param9", 30);
parameters.Add("Param10", 3);
parameters.Add("Param11", "2018-01-28");
parameters.Add("Param12", true);
parameters.Add("Param13", true);

var insertedId = await connection.ExecuteAsync(query, parameters, transaction);
```

Give it a try, it should work.

Comment: The params var is a DynamicParameters object like what you said.

Comment: You can see every param value and SqlType in the screenshots.